# Nmap script doesn't provide an answer

Tags: nmap

I'm running windows 11 and kali linux on Vmware, I tried to run Nmap script on smb with verbose mode and doesn't provide me with an answer.

```
nmap --script smb-enum-shares.nse -p445 192.168.189.129 -v
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-02-19 14:58 EST
NSE: Loaded 1 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 14:58
Completed NSE at 14:58, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating Ping Scan at 14:58
Scanning 192.168.189.129 [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 14:58, 0.00s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 14:58
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 14:58, 13.00s elapsed
Initiating Connect Scan at 14:58
Scanning 192.168.189.129 [1 port]
Discovered open port 445/tcp on 192.168.189.129
Completed Connect Scan at 14:58, 0.00s elapsed (1 total ports)
NSE: Script scanning 192.168.189.129.
Initiating NSE at 14:58
Completed NSE at 14:58, 0.01s elapsed
Nmap scan report for 192.168.189.129
Host is up (0.00077s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds

NSE: Script Post-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 14:58
Completed NSE at 14:58, 0.00s elapsed
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.31 seconds
```

I thought it was firewall so I disabled firewall and all it's rules but still got nothing.

Note:

I'm sharing C folder and Download folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by opening smb on the machine.

Steps:

1. Open Control Panel.
2. Select Programs > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off > SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support.
3. Check SMB 1.0/CIFS Client, and then press Enter.

should I delete the question or there is option to flag as solved?

Answer (score 0):

SMB Shares either need anonymous login enabled or you need to provide credentials.

Comment: Windows 11 does not have anonymous logins too iirc.